# How to get the country code using country name

Tags: c#, .net, cultureinfo

I want to be able to get country code using country name. As of now I'm doing this:

```
var regions = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
                         .Select(x => new RegionInfo(x.LCID));

var selectedRegion = regions.FirstOrDefault(region => 
                                                region.EnglishName.Contains(countryName));
```

Where CountryName in my case is "Tanzania". It is not giving the country code even though in the regions it is present. It always returns null.

Can you please suggest/enlighten me on how to get this done.

Comment: Are you sure it's present? After googling, it seems that C#'s culture list doesn't include Tanzania.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `CultureInfo` type has an `EnglishName` property which does contain an English (Tanzania) but as far as I can see not the region.

```
var cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);
var tanzaniaCulture = cultures.FirstOrDefault(i => i.EnglishName == "English (Tanzania)");
```

Comment: Change a method name to GetCultures. :P

Comment: @Dan D Thanks a lot for the info. Will this work for all the Countries?

Comment: What if i have country name like this "Niederlande" which is in german i guess, the suggested code fails. How to handle such cases?

Comment: @GaurangDave thanks for the feedback, I've updated the answer.  I believe you'll have to install a language pack and set your culture to German in order to handle "Niederlande"

Comment: @DanD after installing the language pack of respective one, will "English (Country)" will work should i need to replace "English" with its respective language name?